# Gulp don't move file

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm trying to move file from a directory to an other with gulp, but when i run my gulpfile, nothing happens, and i have this output

```
[19:25:22] Using gulpfile ~/Dev/Anikey/gulpfile.js
[19:25:22] Starting 'default'...
[19:25:22] Finished 'default' after 19 ms
```

My gulpfile.js :

```js
const {src, dest} = require('gulp');

function copy() {
    return src('src/public/style/*.css')
        .pipe(dest('dist/style/'))
}

exports.default = copy;
```

Do someone know how to fix that please ?

Comment: This path `~/Dev/Anikey/gulpfile.js` is real ?

Comment: And if you try `const gulp = require('gulp');` and `return gulp.src` and `gulp.dest` ?

Comment: This is not the full path, and I already try `gulp.src` and `gulp.dest`

Comment: I added an answer. Can you tell me it's good ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix the problem myself by using npm instead of yarn. To replace yarn, I deleted all dependencies file and then do a `npm install`, and just after a `npx gulp - - watch` and it works

Answer (score 0):

I found this https://fettblog.eu/gulp-4-parallel-and-series/

As mentionned in this article, the new task execution using gulp 4 required `gulp.series` for sequential execution and `gulp.parallel` for parallel execution.

So try to add a build task with series like this, even if you have only 1 task :

```
const gulp = require('gulp');

const copy = () => {
    return gulp.src('src/public/style/*.css')
       .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/style/'))
}

const build = gulp.series(copy);

exports.default = build;
```

Comment: No it don't work to, but i find the solution, I use npm instead of yarn, and it work, thanks for help

Comment: @Vildevil Ok great, then add an answer with your solution and check it as resolved :) It can help other people, thanks!